# Convert double HOURS to MINUTES

Tags: android

I have 2 EDIT Text in my APP with hours and minutes.

i have that double:

```
    double hour;
                try {
                    hour= Double.parseDouble(dayhour.getText().toString().replace(',', '.'));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    hour = 0; 
                }

  double minute;

                try {
                    minute= Double.parseDouble(dayminute.getText().toString().replace(',', '.'));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    minute= 0; 
                }
```

After get hour value i want convert to minutes. because i want know all time in minutes example: 3:42 = 222 minutes.

What i need do?

Comment: you could make it very easy by using DateFormatter or TimeFormatter classes.
Is there a reason youre take hour in x,y format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)change hours to minutes
2)Add minutes

```
double allTime = hour * 60 + minute; // allTime - in minutes
```

Comment: Thank ... really help me =]

Answer (score 0):

You can try a very elegant way

```
minute += TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(hour);
```